# How to use options var in jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a script, called **[jQuery DOM Line](https://github.com/gilmoreorless/jquery-dom-line)**, which I would like to use. It allows me to draw a line between to divs by inserting my vars. The author tells me to use it like:

```
$.line(fromPoint, toPoint[, options]);
```

One of the options is called `className`, which I would like to use to add an extra `.blue` class to `.jquery-line`, so all in all the created div looks like `<div class="jquery-line blue">`.

The default options look like this:

```
$.line.defaults = {
    className: 'jquery-line',
    lineWidth: 1,
    lineColor: '#000',
    returnValues: false
};
```

I draw my line like this:

```
var firstDot = $(this);
var secondDot = dots.eq( currentIndex + 1 + offset);
firstDot.y = firstDot.offset().top;
firstDot.x = firstDot.offset().left;
secondDot.y = secondDot.offset().top;
secondDot.x = secondDot.offset().left;
$.line(firstDot, secondDot);
```

**How can I add the extra className?** I have tried some things like:

```
$.line(firstDot, secondDot, [className: 'blue']);
```

which does not work. As I am not used to the syntax he is using, could anybody help me out? I know it must be something easy…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin is asking for a [JavaScript Object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp) so instead of passing an [array](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp), as you are doing right now, pass an object like this:

```
$.line(firstDot, secondDot, {className: "blue"});
```

or:

```
var myProperties = {className: "blue", lineWidth: 3, lineColor: "pink"};

$.line(firstDot, secondDot, myProperties);
```

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets means that the argument is optional, so

```
 $.line(fromPoint, toPoint[, options]);
```

means that you can call the function either like

```
 $.line(firstDot, secondDot);
```

or like

```
 $.line(firstDot, secondDot, options);
```

You should try to call it like this:

```
 $.line(firstDot, secondDot, {className: 'jquery-line blue'})
```

Also notice that the package includes a option for `lineColor` -- so you may want to call it like this instead;

```
 $.line(firstDot, secondDot, {lineColor: 'blue'})
```